# Is there an IPython line magic for capturing the output of a single line of code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, stdout

I need to capture the output of a single line of code within an IPython notebook cell. There are other lines of code in the cell and I do not want to capture their output. What is the best way to do this? Is there a line magic that can do this, or should I just move the line to its own cell?

Here is an example of what I am after:

In [1]:

```
%%capture output

import h2o
h2o.init()

train_fr = h2o.H2OFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]})
test_fr = h2o.H2OFrame({'a': [4], 'b': [7], 'c': [10]})

drf = h2o.estimators.H2ORandomForestEstimator()
drf.train(y = 'c', training_frame = train_fr)

print(drf.model_performance(test_data = test_fr))
h2o.shutdown()
```

In [2]:

```
with open('model_performance.txt', mode = 'w') as file:
    
    file.write(output.stdout) # full of junk
```

Desired contents of `model_performance.txt`:

```
ModelMetricsRegression: drf
** Reported on test data. **

MSE: 1.690000000000002
RMSE: 1.3000000000000007
MAE: 1.3000000000000007
RMSLE: 0.12576938728903375
Mean Residual Deviance: 1.690000000000002
```

Comment: I've read this several times over and still have no idea what you are trying to do, but _ (the underscore character) is assigned the output of the last unassigned expression.  Maybe that will help.

Comment: @Riley Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried that already and it did not work. The text file was completely blank.

Comment: Are you just wanting to write the output of `print(drf.model_performance(test_data = test_fr))` to file?

Comment: @Riley Yes. I know how to do it if I put that line in its own cell, but I am wondering if there is another way.